# Do I need to allocate memory for a char pointer to a constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I have a constructor for my Arduino-code which is something like the following:

```
class X {
  private:
    char* _name;
  public:
    X(char*);
}

X::X(char* name) {
  _name = name;
}
```

My question is: do I need to allocate a char buffer instead of just relying on the string pointer that was passed? I am not operating on the string (other than to shorten it). I don't seem to be running into any issues yet, but I wanted to verify.

This is specific to arduino, but responses on C and C++ would be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Basically, with the way the code is now, you are requiring that name have a lifetime greater than the lifetime of the instance of the class.  If name is always a string literal, i.e., X("foo"), then this is acceptable.  Otherwise, the caller would have to allocate the string, which is an odd and error prone contract to require.

I would suggest duplicating the string always in the constructor, unless it is clear that it is always expected to be string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't need to allocate a buffer but it's probably more robust.  Especially since you're on an embedded system, likey with no debugger so if someone passes you a string from the caller's stack you're hosed.  Trying to figure out where that kind of problem lies is like a needle in a haystack.  In short, if someone passes you some data, it's very hard to guarantee that memory will persist, so you're better off to take care of the allocation yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You may run into issues, in this case.

```
X foo() {

      char ar[10];
      strcpy(ar,"Hello");

      X obj(ar);

      return obj;
} // ar is deallocated here.
```

But returned object's member variable `_name` still pointing the `ar` which was earlier on the stack. So, it is better to allocate memory and then free it when no longer needed.